# does requests make the retry method execute after some seconds?

Tags: python, python-requests

here is my code.

```
import requests,time
proxies = {'http':'36.33.1.177:21219'}
url='http://218.94.78.61:8080/newPub/service/json/call?serviceName=sysBasicManage&methodName=queryOutputOtherPollutionList&paramsJson=%7B%22ticket%22:%22451a9846-058b-4944-86c6-fccafdb7d8d0%22,%22parameter%22:%7B%22monitorSiteType%22:%2202%22,%22enterpriseCode%22:%22320100000151%22,%22monitoringType%22:%222%22%7D%7D'

i = 0
a = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=10)
s = requests.Session()
s.mount(url, a)
for x in xrange(1,1000):
    time.sleep(1)
    print x
    try:
        r= s.get(url,proxies=proxies)
        print r
    except Exception as ee:
        i = i + 1
        print ee
        print 'i=%s' % i
```

the proxies is a little unstabitily，so I set up the max_retries, but it still have exception sometime, so is there some method to  execute after some secondes at every retry??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just with `requests` library it's not possible. However you can use external library like [backoff](https://github.com/litl/backoff).

`backoff` provides a decorator and you wrap it around your function. Sample code:

```
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.constant,
                      requests.exceptions.RequestException,
                      max_tries=10, interval=10)
def get_url(url):
    return requests.get(url)
```

The above code waits for 10 seconds for next retry on every exception of `requests.exceptions.RequestException` and it tries for 10 times, as specified in `max_tries`.

Comment: sorry.I forget it.I use stackoverflow for just few days. thanks again.

Comment: so can you help me for this question:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324934/by-using-django-orm-to-operate-the-mysql-database-there-are-some-idle-mysqld-ho

Comment: I checked, sorry I don't really know whats the issue.