# By using django orm to operate the MySQL database, there are some idle mysqld. How to close them?

Tags: python, django, mysql

[image]

I type `htop`, then I got this.So we can see the TIME+ tab, there are some mysqld whose time is 00:00:00, it I want to close because it occupy lot of memories. My app have lots of jobs to operate mysql dababase, if the mysqld is not closed timely, mysql will have the error:
`OperationalError: (1135, "Can't create a new thread (errno 11); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug")`

How to resove it?
My django version is 1.6.5.

now in my mysql client, I type `show processlist;`, I got this sitiations:(there are lots of mysql process is sleep. Is it because that I use django orm, so the orm do not close the database connection in time？ And how to close it in time?
[image]

Comment: Django is not responsible for starting mysqld - that's the MySQL daemon that should be started by your system on startup. You need to check the init scripts.

Comment: You might want to consider implementing [connection pooling](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mysqlpool/0.1-7).

Comment: so it is just about mysql, if I change the database type,for example,postgrep or others. Is it possible for the django orm setting?

Comment: @DanielRoseman @BurhanKhalid hi, I update my question. Can you help me? As I know, the django doest not have connnection pool, if I use other databases, like postgreps? Is there some methods? Now I use `from django.db import connection` and after the code used the orm, then `connection.close()`.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/databases/#connection-management

There is a variable `CONN_MAX_AGE` that you can set to 0 to close db connection immediately after request. But this is supposed to be default behavior. Can you check what is your `CONN_MAX_AGE` is? `./manage.py diffsettings | grep CONN_MAX_AGE` will do the trick.

Comment: the result is `DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'NAME': 'btc', 'TEST_MIRROR': None, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'TEST_NAME': None, 'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC', 'TEST_COLLATION': None, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 'USER': 'root', 'TEST_CHARSET': None, 'PASSWORD': 'aaaaa', 'PORT': '3306'}}`

Comment: thanks. So as BurhanKhalid said,is there some method to add connection pool because that django do not have connect pool?

Comment: How do you start your django server? uwsgi/gunicorn/runserver/...? With how many threads?

Comment: Also, are you sure the connections are held by your django server? What happens if you shut it down?

Comment: at the beginning, I use `runserver`, debug is true. And I found that whatever I set the debug true or false, there are still 2 process about `runserver`(python manage.py runserver and /usr/bin/python manage.py runserver). Then I use gunicorn, `gunicorn btcproject.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8002 -w 2`. That seems that it because better that before. I do not know why.